# Mouse and Steam Controller not working

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, mouse

I’m not sure why but I turned on my computer to find my Steam Controller was no longer working. I thought this was odd, and clicked on what I thought was the Steam Controller in device manager to install the correct drivers. Turned out it was my mouse and it completely made my mouse stop functioning.

I’ve been trying for the past 24 hours to fix both now and I’ve tried just about everything from going into safe mode, uninstalling the drivers and hoping Windows would install them themselves, trying to install the drivers by picking from a list of drivers on my computer, nothing seems to work. And now I look at device manager, my mouse is listed as two different devices both called USB receiver, and my Steam Controller is listed as 5 different devices called Steam Controller.

[image: screenshot]

On top of that I have three unknown devices without any other USBs plugged in besides my Bluetooth adapter. I can’t go back to a restore point since I don’t seem to have any.

Is there anything I can do? Any help would be really appreciated.

My mouse is a Logitech G602 gaming mouse if it makes any difference. The software for it is installed, that's the only thing in the support downloads on Logitech's website.